# Change css3 icons color on mouse over with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this ok css3 icon created with css.
http://jsfiddle.net/5c9gN/

JS:

```
$('.ok').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.ok:after, .ok:before').css('background','#ccc');
    $(this).css('background','#33CC33');
});
$('.ok').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.ok:after, .ok:before').css('background','#ccc');
    $(this).css('background','#ccc');
});
```

CSS:

```
.ok{height:40px; width:40px; display:block; position:relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;} 

.ok:after, .ok:before{content:''; height:32px; width:10px; display:block; background:   #ccc; position:absolute; top:6px; left:18px; transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);}

.ok:before{height:16px; transform:rotate(-45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); top:18px; left:6px;}
```

And I'm having a little issue while trying to change the color of the icon. It always changes the background color not the icon. 
Could anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using only CSS:

### DEMO

```css
.ok:hover:after, .ok:hover:before {
    background: #33CC33;
}
```

Comment: @TusharGupta I don't get the purpose of your edit? What i'm missing?!

Comment: I just added syntax highlighting for css.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
.ok.mouseover:after, .ok.mouseover:before{
     background:    #33CC33;
}
```

and update your JS code to this

```
$('.ok').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('mouseover');
});
$('.ok').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('mouseover');
});
```